# How to translate html content in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.7

I am having some content in .html file in checkout page, I want to translate that content to french but I am unable to translate. I tried many methods but still not getting.I translate all phtml files by placing the text in echo and placed the word in csv file.